# Using multiple login fields, email or phone number in Django All Auth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-custom-user

I am using Django All Auth to authenticate user but I need to use phone number or email field when logging in user. I extended user class as follows:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

My signup form looks like this:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=10,label='phone_number')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        user.save()
```

Phone number is saved in the backend using this but I need to authenticate user if he enters either email or phone number. What class do i need to extend for Django All Auth. I have read a lot of questions but could not find anything good.

If I place ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number' in settings.py , it authenticates via phone but not email.

**EDIT 1:**

I created a file backends.py and I wrote this code

```
class PhoneNumberBackend(object):
    """
    Custom Phone Number Backend to perform authentication via phone number
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()

        try:
            user = my_user_model.objects.get(phone_number=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user # return user on valid credentials
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None # return None if custom user model does not exist 
        except:
            return None # return None in case of other exceptions

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            return my_user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Settings.py looks like this now:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # 'userauth.backends.PhoneNumberBackend',
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)
```

It should authenticate using phone number and if not then fallback to other authentication methods , right? It does not work like that.

Comment: I did somewhat similar stuff way back. I think you should subclass `BaseUserManager` class and define your own custom user manager with couple of tweaks.

Comment: But django all auth settings ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD would still be applicable even if we use BaseUserManager. No?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to make an authentication backend in djagno
like this for email

```
class EmailAuthentication(object):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None
    except:
        return None
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    except:
return None
```

you can make another one for phone number 
but make sure to make them unique on your database so no one will have to accounts with same credentials 
and you can check it in the form clean method like this 
again this is for email

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(' user with this email is already registered -- Try loginigin or resting the password')    
    return email
```

then you should put the auth backend in the settings file and don't forget to include the original username backend of django

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'account.authentication.EmailAuthentication',
]
```

in the previous code i assumed your auth backend is inside a file called authentication in the account app

then in the view you will authenticate the user then log him in

```
  username = form.cleaned_data['username']
  password = form.cleaned_data['password2']
  user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  if user:
      login(request, user)
```

or you can use the LoginView from django.contrib.auth.views to make it easier

Comment: As I am using Django All Auth so it already has AuthenticationBackend which we should be able to extend somehow to allow phone number or any other field as login. I have made another backend just for phone but still confused if its the right way or not

Comment: this way you extend it, to reassure your self this way is from django2by example book, and i have used it with a little modifications

Comment: when you put the auth backends on the settings django try to authenticate the user with every one in succession and if it find one auth that know the user it will stop

Comment: i see there no need to make two exceptions if the same will return the same result,if  you want you can share the code on github so i can edit it or see the full cycle of the authentication , i am not expert to give right Assumptions

Comment: It is not on git yet. What I can tell is that the login view being used is the default view of allauth or you think i need to override it?

Comment: No, there is no need to override it, because we already avoided the problem of the log in when we replaced phone or email argument of the auth function by username so it won't make any conflict                                                                 you can see my code for email auth here [https://github.com/mohamed591195/social-site-like-facebook-]

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try to play around and update my question too